# How can I make something move in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I made a div and a button. Made a function on button's click that set div's margin (i.e move it). But how can I make it move on every click. Whenever I hit the button it do moves, (without refreshing the page) when I press that button again it don't work? How to make it move on every click of button! Here's my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            font-family:ebrima;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body onload="" id="demo">

    <div name="player" style="float:right; height:32px; width:32px; background:green;" id="myDiv"></div>
    <form name="myForm" method="post">  
        <button value="MOVE" type="button" name="moveButton" onClick="move()">MOVE</button>
    </form>


    <script>
        function move()
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").style.margin="0px 10px 0px 0px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to click "accept" on your favorite answer! Let me know if you have any additional questions!

Comment: use css translate to move or change the position of element. Check out paul irish's blog http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Answer (score 2):

I would advise using jQuery, which makes a lot of javascript quite simple.

Here's a sample jQuery animation for you:

```
<script>
    function move() {
        $("#myDiv").animate({left:'+=250px'});
    }
</script>
```

This will shift the button over by 250px every time you trigger the function.

Note that you'll need to add jQuery to your project (which is trivial). [The jQuery website has some well organized tutorials](http://learn.jquery.com) that should help you find your way around JavaScript and jQuery - happy coding!

Comment: Fail answer. jQuery is a huge library for such a simple problem.

Comment: Oh gosh...and the update :( w3schools is known to be a somewhat poor website.

Comment: @m59 - I am aware of w3schools's troubled past and hesitate before advising it, but they have improved their website and I find that the organization is pretty friendly for beginners. If I felt I could throw an entire book at the asker, I would have pulled up MDN, but I find that they can be a bit terse for beginners, even if they're higher quality if you already know your way around most of JS/JQ.

Comment: Understatement of the year. W3schools is just bad. Show me _one_ good tutorial there, and I'll tell you why it isn't.

Comment: Nonetheless, the OP should be commended for learning how to do things without a library. It is crazy ridiculous that you suggested jQuery for this. People seriously include jQuery (huge library) to save 10 lines of work. This sort of answer encourages that.

Comment: @m59 - Regarding the size of jQuery "for such a simple problem", consider how much shorter and easier to read my answer is than yours. Next consider the fact that this person is either: a - working on a pet project where considering size isn't important at all, or b - working on a full project and this is just the beginning, and by the time they're done, jQuery's minified form will just be a small part of it. Every line of their code will benefit tremendously from using jQuery.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Feel free to offer your favorite competitor. Heck, your reputation is high enough that you could outright edit my answer without so much as a review to tout a different website.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare you should do so. Moreover, it could be considered too radical to put the words "[some other resource] has some good tutorials" into your mouth.

Comment: @JanDvorak - If I knew of a website as well designed for beginners, I'd offer it as I am aware of w3schools troubled past. Over the years, however, they have updated their website to address the criticisms. I believe that most people who continue to simply bash it and people mentioning it, like yourself (believe it or not, I was once one of you), haven't bothered to check the website in the past year and see that the old inaccuracies were fixed.

Comment: @JanDvorak Please stop complaining about such pointless things. You don't have to be so rude about enforcing your own opinions. Such childish behavior.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek would nicer words have helped? My point still stands: W3schools is a very bad resource, and it's not a pointless thing to point out.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare once again - show me a w3schools tutorial on javascript or jQuery you consider good. If I agree, I'll retract my vote. If I don't, I'll tell you why.

Comment: Or, should I edit in a better resource / edit out the last paragraph?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek removed the link and upvoted. Do you approve of my newest behavior?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, I understand w3schools isn't the best resource out there. Although ArtOfWarfare does have a point that they have been improving there tutorials and are better then before, along with being easier to understand for a beginner. Although other sources like MDN are better and more accurate/detailed, it may be harder for someone who just started to fully understand. With respect to a starter audience that are just getting their feet wet: I don't think w3schools is as bad as you consider it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's why I'm asking for a specific tutorial to review. I assert "notExist tutorial such that notExists a serious sin in that tutorial". Thus, the burden of proof should be on the opponent. I can prove myself a much weaker statement, however: "for an arbitrarily chosen sample tutorial, notExists a serious sin in that tutorial". Or I could list one sin per tutorial, but that would amount of more than just a few comments. Trust me, I've tried. Also, I'm curious about what the answerer considers a good tutorial.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I accept the decision to remove the link. I would have preferred if you would have found an equally beginner friendly website that you approved of and replaced it with that. You previously objected to the idea of putting words in my mouth - you could have suggested the website (you still can, in fact), I could have reviewed it, decided it seemed as quick/easy to get started with as W3Schools and seemed superior to W3Schools as far as the quality of the information it provided, and replaced it myself. Thus you'd be suggesting words for me, not saying them for me.

Comment: I've tried to find a good tutorial, but then I realised that the jQuery website hosts one: http://learn.jquery.com/ (mostly a jQuery tutorial, but it also contains a javascript 101). I think I've already seen some of it and found it good. It looks pretty good from what I've just looked at

Comment: @JanDvorak - They look pretty solid. I added a link to them. Mainly the thing that I liked about W3Schools was the concise examples and the organization of their tutorials. They offered a pretty natural order for working your way from simple concepts to more complicated ones, and ultimately were pretty comprehensive. I think the same things can be said the jquery page you pointed me at.

Comment: Another positives I've noticed that don't hold for the w3schools site: syntax highlighting (w3schools is black&white); proper indentation (w3schools is  mostly unindented); uses `console.log` for introductory I/O (w3schools uses `document.write` - ew). I also like how they put "A for asynchronous" at the start of the Ajax tutorial.

Comment: @JanDvorak - `console.log` doesn't work for all browsers (some versions of IE crash.) But it's true that w3schools fails to format their code.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare `console.log` fails in IE7 and older (who supports them  today?) and in IE8 if the console isn't open. But even if you intend to have `console.log`s in production code _and_ you want oldIE support, you can simply do `window.console = window.console || {log:function(){}}`. Moreover, even if you can't use the dev tools, `alert` fares much better than `document.write` for "general I/O".

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to set the new margin each time. After using it, change the variable's value so that next time, it will move somewhere else.

```
var x = 10;
function move() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.margin="0px "+x+"px 0px 0px";
  x = x+10;
}
```

First, don't use inline js (like onclick). Read some of these results: **[**Why is inline js bad?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)***

Instead, attach your event listener with javascript:

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById('my-btn');
myBtn.addEventListener('click', move);
```

Your code would be more readable/efficient and easier to debug like this:

```
//cache element reference in advance
var document.getElementById("myDiv")

function move() {
  //just target the property you want to change.
  myDiv.style.marginLeft = x+'px';
  x = x+10;
}
```

Here's a little **[demo (click)](http://jsbin.com/UGazezO/1/edit)** I put together you may enjoy.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('my-div');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('my-btn');

myBtn.addEventListener('click', move);

function move(e) {
  var v = r()+'px '+r()+'px '+r()+'px '+r()+'px';
  myDiv.style.margin = v;
}

function r() {
  return getRandomInt(0, 20);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

And here's a more fun one using `mousemove` rather than `click`. **[Demo here.](http://jsbin.com/UGazezO/2/edit)**

Comment: I think there should be a space after the first `0px`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function move() {
  var elt = document.getElementById("myDiv"),
      currentMargin = parseInt(elt.style.marginRight, 10);
  elt.style.marginRight = currentMargin + 10 + 'px';
}
```